# How do I send low level GPIB commands using PyVISA?

Tags: python, visa, gpib, pyvisa

So I have initialized a GPIB instrument like so:

```
import pyvisa
rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager()
kk = rm.open_resource('GPIB0::1::INSTR')

# kk is some Keithley 2400 source meter unit
```

According to the [PyVISA docs](https://pyvisa.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/resources.html#pyvisa.resources.GPIBInstrument.send_command), `kk` has a `send_command` method to write GPIB commands.  So I try the following lines, without success:

```
kk.send_command('SDC')
kk.send_command(b'SDC')
```

The [Keithley 2400 manual (PDF)](https://download.tek.com/manual/2400S-900-01_K-Sep2011_User.pdf) shows on page D-9 and D-10 some codes related to GPIB commands, but I don't know what to make of these:
[image: Keithley 2400 SMU User's Manual page D-9]
[image: Keithley 2400 SMU User's Manual page D-10]

#### Question: What is the correct way to send low-level GPIB commands using the `send_command` method of a `GPIBInstrument` instance in PyVISA?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to send the actual byte, not the name of the command.

So to send SDC, you would send b'\x04'